# Updates href values for a limited collection of links on a page

Tags: javascript, dom

As much as it hurts, I've been tasked with writing a script that prepends integration, QA, etc. environment segments to anchor href attributes that link to a series of sites within two specific domains.

Since we can't be certain of adherence to the requirement that content authors always use production URLs (without these segments) this script covers cases where the wrong segment is present in a particular downstream environment.

We do know the domains and finite list of environments.

```
/*
    Updates URL environment segments in page links (anchor hrefs)

    1. Determines the current environment by parsing location.hostname.
    2. Selects a list of links with absolute URIs or network-path references:
    (`a[href^="http"], a[href^="//"]`).
    3. Loops over the list of links and takes action only on items that contain
    _domainone.com_ or _domaintwo.com_ in the `href` attribute.
        a. If environment is production, removes the environment segment
        b. If downstream environment, adds or updates environmnet segment to
        match the current environment.

    Currently supports domainone.com and domaintwo.com domains. To
    add additional domains, update the `domainRegEx` variable. This script also
    assumes a finite list of environment names (authoring, integration,
    localhost, qa, and sys). To support additional environments, update the
    `envRegEx` variable.
*/
(function(window) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const domainRegEx = /(domainone\.com)|(domaintwo\.com)/i;
        const envRegEx = /authoring\.|integration\.|localhost\.|qa\.|sys\./i;
        const environment = location.hostname.match(envRegEx);
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http"], a[href^="//"]');

        for (let i = links.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            const link = links[i];
            const href = link.getAttribute('href');
            if (domainRegEx.test(href)) {
                // If production, remove any environment segments ...
                if (environment === null) {
                    link.setAttribute('href', href.replace(envRegEx, ''));
                } else {
                    // ... else if downstream environment, ensure correct environment segment.
                    if (envRegEx.test(href)) {
                        link.setAttribute('href', href.replace(envRegEx, `${environment[0]}`));
                    } else {
                        link.setAttribute('href', href.replace(domainRegEx, `${environment[0]}$1`));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}(window));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's no need to wrap this all in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). You aren't introducing any variables in the top scope, so no need to prevent them from leaking. Though it will become more useful when you follow my advice of introducing some helper functions. But even then there's no need to safe-guard the `window` global (as you aren't worried about the `location` and `document` globals).
- Why are you running the loop backwards? Better use a looping construct that's meant for dealing with lists, like the [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.
- The `environment` variable contains a result of a regex match and is used like so:

  ```
  // If production, remove any environment segments ...
  if (environment === null) {
  ```

  If you would translate the regex match into an actual environment name, the code would become much more self-explanatory:

  ```
  if (environment === "production") {
  ```
- For changing the link href value, I'd suggest extracting helper functions like `stripEnvironment()` and `replaceEnvironment()`, which could be used as:

  ```
  link.setAttribute('href', stripEnvironment(href));
  link.setAttribute('href', replaceEnvironment(href, environment));
  ```
- If you want to have the domains and environments lists to be easily extensible, regex is probably not the best choice. Better to define them as arrays of strings which you can later transform into regexes using the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor.
- Your regexes look a bit too loose. The `/sys\./` pattern would also match `linksys.`. You should at least anchor them at word boundary using `\b`.

Comment: This is good stuff, thanks for taking the time. Originally I did have a function to determine the current environment (hence the IIFE), but abandoned it when I went with the RegEx. I'm running the loop backwards, solely because I'm under the impression that it is the most performant way to iterate over a potentially large list. I will look into converting the domains and environments list into arrays and populating a RegEx from those (though this list should remain fairly static). Will definitely add the boundary special character. Thanks, again!

Comment: Don't tune the performance beforehand. First run the code and see if it actually needs any tuning. It'll most likely be fast enough. If you do find it to be slow, measure the speed before and after tuning to see if it really helped. In your case, the speed of DOM operations is likely to have more performance impact than whichever way you decide to loop over the list.

Comment: Would like to post my refactored code, but unsure if I should add it to my OP, replace the code in my OP, or add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, here is the refactored code based on Rene's suggestions:

```
/*
    Updates URL environment segments in page links (anchor hrefs)

    1. Determines the current environment by parsing location.hostname.
    2. Selects a list of links with absolute URIs or network-path references:
    (`a[href^="http"], a[href^="//"]`).
    3. Iterates over the list of links and takes action only on items that
    contain _domainone.com_ or _domaintwo.com_ in the `href`
    attribute.
        a. If environment is production, removes the environment segment
        b. If downstream environment, adds or updates environmnet segment to
        match the current environment.

    Supported domain names and environment segments are located in the `domains`
    and `environments` arrays.
*/
(function() {
    const domains = ['domainone.com', 'domaintwo.com'];
    const environments = ['authoring', 'integration', 'localhost', 'qa', 'sys'];
    const domainRegEx = new RegExp(
        domains.map(domain => `(${domain})`.replace(/\./gi, '\\.')).join('|'),
        'i',
    );
    const envRegEx = new RegExp(
        `\\b(?:${environments.map(env => `${env}\\.`).join('|')})`,
        'i',
    );

    function getEnvironment(host) {
        const match = host.match(envRegEx);

        if (match) {
            return match[0];
        }

        return 'production';
    }

    function hasEnvironment(href) {
        return envRegEx.test(href);
    }

    function isDomainSupported(href) {
        return domainRegEx.test(href);
    }

    function addUpdateEnvironment(href, env) {
        if (hasEnvironment(href)) {
            return href.replace(envRegEx, env);
        }

        return href.replace(domainRegEx, `${env}$1`);
    }

    function removeEnvironment(href) {
        return href.replace(envRegEx, '');
    }

    function updateLinks() {
        const environment = getEnvironment(location.hostname);
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http"], a[href^="//"]');

        links.forEach((link) => {
            const href = link.getAttribute('href');

            if (isDomainSupported(href)) {
                /*
                    If production, remove environment segment. Otherwise, ensure
                    correct environment segment.
                */
                link.setAttribute(
                    'href',
                    environment === 'production' ?
                        removeEnvironment(href) :
                        addUpdateEnvironment(href, environment),
                );
            }
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateLinks);
}());
```

Comment: You could also get rid of `environment[0]` by creating a function that returns you the environment string. Also the regex-checks are kind of low-level. Instead of reading `domainRegEx.test(href)` I would rather read code like `isSupportedDomain(href)`. Also you could combine add/replaceEnvironment to a single function who's task is to set the environment sub-domain regardless if the URL has sub-domain.